# How to get percentiles?

Tags: mysql

I have 3 fields in my table which I can order by (among some other fields), and I would like to create a single query that will -- ***after* doing some grouping, etc.** -- give me all the rows, along with the percentiles of that each relative to each of those 4 fields.

How do I do this? I'm guessing I need a subquery but I'm not sure how.

---

Sample input would be something like this:

```
age | first_name | last_name | votes
----+------------+-----------+-------
 10 | Bob        | Smith     |  2
 10 | Bob        | Smith     |  3
 50 | John       | Adams     |  1
 50 | John       | Adams     |  1
 50 | John       | Adams     |  2
100 | Andy       | Johnson   |  2
```

Sample output should be like this, after some transformations (e.g. adding up the votes):

```
age | first_name | last_name | votes | age_per | first_name_per | last_name_per
----+------------+-----------+-------+---------+----------------+-------------
 10 | Bob        | Smith     |  5    |   33    |    66          |    99
 50 | John       | Adams     |  4    |   66    |    99          |    33
100 | Andy       | Johnson   |  2    |   99    |    33          |    66
```

Comment: pardon my ignorance, there is not enough information to carry on, are you looking for percentage out of each column, or percentage out of 4-columns?

Comment: It's easy to get the minimum, maximum, average of values in a group. Please clarify the "the percentiles of that". What "percentiles" do you want? And "after doing some grouping, etc." -- doing what grouping? It's really impossible for someone to write a query based on these vague statements...

Comment: @ajreal: Sorry, I meant out of each column -- there would be 3 new columns in the result row (one for the percentile of each column).
Dan: Percentile as in, median = 50th percentile, 1st quartile = 25th percentile, etc.

Comment: @Dan: I added an example, hope that's clearer.

Comment: WTH does it mean to be in the 66th percentile of first names? I'm out.

Comment: The example confused me even more. Are you trying to calculate the percentile of votes for a given first or last name? Ex, "I am in the 90th percentile of votes for people named Justin"? Is this some kind of "rate my <insert body part here>" app?

Comment: How do you get 33 for 'age_per' for bob smith? 2 bobs out of 6 names gives .33, but 3 johns out of 6 names gives 0.50, not 66. How the heck are you deriving those numbers?

Comment: I think OP is refer to `33=1 position, 66=2nd position`

Comment: @Dan: If you order the first names, Bob is 2nd -- or the 66th percentile. (What ajreal said is correct.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT age
     , first_name 
     , last_name 
     , SUM(votes) AS votes
     , ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT age)
         FROM tableX AS a
         WHERE a.age <= t.age
       ) * 100 / distinct_age_count
       AS age_per
     , ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT first_name)
         FROM tableX AS f
         WHERE f.first_name <= t.first_name
       ) * 100 / distinct_first_name_count
       AS first_name_per
     , ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT last_name)
         FROM tableX AS l
         WHERE l.last_name <= t.last_name
       ) * 100 / distinct_last_name_count
       AS last_name_per
FROM
    tableX AS t
  CROSS JOIN
    ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT age) AS distinct_age_count
      FROM tableX
    ) AS ad
  CROSS JOIN
    ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT first_name) AS distinct_first_name_count
      FROM tableX
    ) AS fd
  CROSS JOIN
    ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT last_name) AS distinct_last_name_count
      FROM tableX
    ) AS ld
GROUP BY age
       , first_name
       , last_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? (I don't have a MySQL instance to test it on right now)

```
SELECT age, 
       first_name, 
       last_name, 
       SUM(votes), 
       COUNT(age) / (SELECT COUNT(age) FROM table t WHERE t.age = age) as age_per, 
       COUNT(first_name) / (SELECT COUNT(first_name) FROM table t WHERE t.first_name = first_name) as first_name_per, 
       COUNT(last_name) / (SELECT COUNT(last_name) FROM table t WHERE t.last_name = last_name) as last_name_per
FROM table
GROUP BY age, first_name, last_name
```